# Facebook User Taggable Friends

Tags: facebook

I'm very new to iOS development and am having trouble figuring out how to convert Facebook's tutorial on Facebook's user taggable friends from Objective C to Swift.
Here is the link to Facebook's [tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/taggable_friends).

I tried writing `var request : FBSDKGraphRequest
            request = FBSDKGraphRequest.initWithGraphPath` ...
but FBSDKGraphRequest doesn't have initWithGraphPath.

When I try to follow Brian J Coleman's [tutorial](http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-get-facebook-friends-in-swift/), Xcode says FBRequest is an undeclared type.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way yo would convert the code [in this document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/taggable_friends)

```
    let params:Dictionary<String, String> = ["randomParam":"paramValue"]
    var request : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(
        graphPath: "/{user-id}/taggable_friends",
        parameters: params, 
        HTTPMethod: "GET"
    )

    request.startWithCompletionHandler { (
        connection: FBSDKGraphRequestConnection!,
        result: AnyObject!,
        error:NSError!) -> Void in
        // Handle the result
    }
```